# How to change the format of laravel 5 json error message format?

Tags: json, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to access laravel 5 error messages and append into the error div through ajax. But problem is that laravel returning error message with square brackets and these square brackets are not accessing.

In the ajax i can access success message like this

`{"success":"Record has been inserted successfully!"}`

```
success: function(data){ alert(data.success); }
```

But laravel returning error messages with square brackets

```
{
   "u_name":["The u name must be at least 4 characters."],
   "u_email":["The u email has already been taken."]
}
```

Following trick does not work

```
error:function(data){
      alert(data.u_name);
  }
```

UserController.php `// Just for reference`

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'u_name' => 'required|unique:fl_user|min:4',
    'u_email' => 'required|unique:fl_user',
]);
```

So is there possible to remove the square brackets from json in laravel 5? or how can i access them as array in ajax? I would like to appreciate if someone guide me regarding this.

Comment: The square brackets are arrays, so just access them as arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Your code applies different validation rules to one field and it means that some of them may be violated. One error message is used for one validation rules. All of the them combined in array that returned back.